# Cannot wake from suspend after 5.1.4 update

Tags: suspend

Black screen after wake from suspend after 5.1.4 update with kernel on 5.3.0-53

Answer (score 0):

Same here, allthough it was like this before 5.1.4 for me I think.

Other people have the same problem: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/issues/219

I'm trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this.